# Syncronize changes in Backbone files

Tags: maven, tomcat, backbone.js, intellij-idea

I have an application that works with Spring on backend and Backbone on frontend. 
To start it I use a Tomcat 6 Maven plugin. 
Also, the app runs in IntelliJ 14.

I want to know if there is a possibility to update automatically the changes I make in the Backbone files, without having to restart the server to see the changes in my browser.

Thanks!